# await asyncio.wait(coroutines) invalid syntax

Tags: python, coroutine, python-asyncio

I have a python program that uses `asyncio` and `await` modules. This is an example program that I have taken from 
[here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/).

```
import asyncio
import os
import urllib.request
import await

@asyncio.coroutine
def download_coroutine(url):
    """
    A coroutine to download the specified url
    """
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    filename = os.path.basename(url)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as file_handle:
        while True:
            chunk = request.read(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            file_handle.write(chunk)
    msg = 'Finished downloading {filename}'.format(filename=filename)
    return msg

@asyncio.coroutine
def main(urls):
    """
    Creates a group of coroutines and waits for them to finish
    """
    coroutines = [download_coroutine(url) for url in urls]
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines)
    for item in completed:
        print(item.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ["http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040a.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040ez.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sb.pdf"]

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(main(urls))
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

I am using `python 3.5.1`.

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\XXXXXXS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 49950 49951
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:29:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I try to run it I get the following error.

```
  File "C:/Cubic/playpen/python/concepts/advanced/coroutines.py", line 29
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have both asyncio and await installed.

I have tried the same thing and I don't get any syntax error either.

```
C:\playpen\python>python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:29:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> async def foo():
...   await bar
...
```

Comment: You are importing a module named `await` and shadowing the keyword. Remove the import.

Answer (score 9):

`await` will raise a `SyntaxError` when used anywhere other than inside of a function defined using the `async` keyword, regardless of whether or not it has been made a coroutine using the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator.

```
import asyncio

async def test():
    pass


async def foo():
    await test()  # No exception raised.

@asyncio.coroutine
def bar():
    await test()  # Exception raised.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your article says:

> The async and await keywords were added in Python 3.5 to define a native coroutine and make them a distinct type when compared with a generator based coroutine. If you’d like an in-depth description of async and await, you will want to check out PEP 492.

This means those kws are not valid in Python 3.4.

I installed right now python 3.5 and tried the `python` interpreter

```
foo@foo-host:~$ python3.5  
Python 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38)  
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> async def foo():  
...     await bar  
...   
>>>
```

Got no syntax error.

Comment: @liv2hak: You've probably installed multiple Python interpreters and gotten mixed up about which one you're using.

Comment: Edited. Check the version when you run an interative interpreter

Comment: @LuisMasuelli - I have updated above. I also get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different issues here.

1. As mentioned by [dirn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978961/dirn) in his comment, you should not be importing `await`. `await` is a built in keyword in Python 3.5. So, remove `import await`.
2. You've mixed the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator and `await` keyword (as [2Cubed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6119465/2cubed) mentions). Instead of the decorator, use `async def` as shown in the [example](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/) you linked to. In other words, instead of:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def download_coroutine(url):
```

use:

```
async def download_coroutine(url):
```

Do the same for `main`.

If you make these changes, your code should run under Python 3.5.